# dropzone action after all files are uploaded

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzonejs this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            try 
            {
                $(".dropzone").dropzone({
                    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
                    maxFilesize: 0.5, // MB
                    uploadMultiple: true,
                    //addRemoveLinks : true,
                    dictDefaultMessage :
                        '<span class="bigger-150 bolder"><i class="icon-caret-right red"></i> Drop files</span> to upload \
                        <span class="smaller-80 grey">(or click)</span> <br /> \
                        <i class="upload-icon icon-cloud-upload blue icon-3x"></i>',
                    dictResponseError: 'Error while uploading file!',               
                    //change the previewTemplate to use Bootstrap progress bars
                    previewTemplate: "<div class=\"dz-preview dz-file-preview\">\n  <div class=\"dz-details\">\n    <div class=\"dz-filename\"><span data-dz-name></span></div>\n    <div class=\"dz-size\" data-dz-size></div>\n    <img data-dz-thumbnail />\n  </div>\n  <div class=\"progress progress-small progress-striped active\"><div class=\"progress-bar progress-bar-success\" data-dz-uploadprogress></div></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-success-mark\"><span></span></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-error-mark\"><span></span></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-error-message\"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>\n</div>"
                });
            } 
            catch(e) 
            {
                alert('Dropzone.js does not support older browsers!');
            }
});

    </script>
```

where exactly can I put a listener do do something (reload/redirect/alert) after ALL files are uploaded?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a generic initialisation script using jQuery for Dropzone

```
Dropzone.options.myDropZoneForm = {
    url: 'url/here',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,       
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*, audio/*, video/*',
    maxFiles: 10,
    init: function () {
        var thisDropzone = this;

        // just showing some dropped files stats
        var totalFiles = 0, completeFiles = 0;
        this.on('addedfile', function(file){
            totalFiles += 1;
            totalFilesFormatted = totalFiles.toFixed(2);
            $('#showTotalFileCount').html(totalFilesFormatted);
        });
        this.on('removedfile', function(file){
            totalFiles -= 1;
            totalFilesFormatted = totalFiles.toFixed(2);
            $('#showTotalFileCount').html(totalFilesFormatted);
        });
        this.on('maxfilesreached', function(file){
            alert('maxFiles reached');
        });
        this.on('maxfilesexceeded', function(file){
            alert('files dropped exceeded maxFiles');
        });
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(){
            // event when files are being sent
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
            // event when files are successfully uploaded
            // you can return a response string and process it here through 'response'
        });
        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
          // event when there's an error
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you iron out things. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need the parameter `completemultiple` which is a function that will be called once all files have been uploaded.

Also fo interest to you:

- `processingmultiple`
- `sendingmultiple`
- `successmultiple`
- `canceledmultiple`

From: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: can you please give me an example? I tried this way but it doesn't work:
init: function() {
             this.on("completemultiple", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
           },

Comment: So you don't see the alert?  Can you check to make sure you have the latest dropzone JS?  Add the completemultiple parameter along the other dropzone parameters like `paramName`.